# Is it possible to capture requests with Postman standalone app?

Tags: postman

I was wondering - is it possible to capture requests with Postman standalone app, when requests are issued NOT by a browser, but a Console App or a Windows service? My app is making AJAX calls to a server, I want these calls to be captured with Postman app.

Comment: Because you deleted the other question i write it here. The linked documentation describes it exemplarily for iOS, below are links to other OS. For each OS you are able to define Proxies for certain protocols in the Networksettings. Whether the applications use this proxy depends on if they consider the system settings. But that's not a postman related _problem_. Some applications allow to define different proxy settings _curl_ has command line parameters for that _Firefox_ has a settings dialog.

Comment: Hi, in Windows 10 if I type proxy I get "Configure proxy server" which opens a dialog window "Internet Properties", if I click LAN Settings, I can check the Proxy Server checkbox. If I do that, I am unable to make any requests at all. So, I cannot set this proxy, I will not be able to use Internet at all

Comment: Besides, I want to capture HTTP requests from console app. I still have no idea how to do that, there is no info on internet about that.

Comment: If I set a proxy like I explained in prev comment, I get "Your connection is not private" for every site I decide to browse, basically browsing is dead.

Comment: The system Proxy settings do not magically make other programs use this settings, they or the library they use to make the http calls need to check if those settings are done and then use the proxy. So if you want to debug your own application, then don't use the port `80` while debugging but the proxy port of post man. If you want to debug `https`  then do some further reading. You really should do some research what a proxy is in general, how a proxy works, and when it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set a proxy for your Console App/Windows service? If yes, then it might be possible.

You need to get the port number from Postman's proxy setting and the IP address from your computer. Apply these two as the proxy for your app, and Postman should hopefully be able to listen in to your requests.

Here's the [blogpost](http://blog.getpostman.com/2016/06/26/using-postman-proxy-to-capture-and-inspect-api-calls-from-ios-or-android-devices/) from where I found this out.

Comment: Hi, yes I saw that article. It is dedicated to mobile devices. I am actually interested in capturing traffic from a Windows console app. I am not sure how that is possible to set proxy in this case.

Comment: Thats the post I read, for some weird reason, it explains how to set proxy in some phone for wifi and on Mac PC. I dont have MAC PC, and I dont need to capture trafic from my phone. I am on Win 10.

Comment: Also, I cannot find Postman.exe at all. Where the hell is it?